# How to copy java.util.list Collection

Tags: java, clone

I am implementing a Java class responsible for ordering java.util.List. The problem comes when I use this class. I'm able to ordering the list but I want to copy the "original" list without modification so that I could register every change made on the original list. The sorted list contains object and one of its fields stores a classification id, and this id it is updated with the index value of the list.

I tried to use clone method and it keeps the list unsorted but the changes made on original list are updated in the clone list too.

Is there any way to accomplish it?

My Code:

```
List<Torero> listaTorero = tbTlgTorerolHome.findByExample(new Torero());
List<Torero> listaToreroTemp = ((List<Torero>) ((ArrayList<Torero>) listaTorero).clone()); 

Clasificacion clasificacion = new Clasificacion();

Iterator<Torero> iterTorero = clasificacion.getClasificacion(listaTorero, torero).iterator(); //Sorting List
```

A Clasificacion method:

```
public List<Torero> getClasificacion(List<Torero> listaToreroTemp, Torero torero)
{

    List<Torero> listaTorero = new ArrayList<Torero>();

    Collections.sort(listaToreroTemp,new ToreroClasifiacionComparator());

    Iterator<Torero> iterTorero = listaToreroTemp.iterator();
    int index=1;
    while(iterTorero.hasNext())
    {
        Torero toreroTemp = iterTorero.next();
        toreroTemp.setNumClasificacion(index);
        listaTorero.add(toreroTemp);
        index=index+1;
    }
    return listaTorero;
}
```

Comment: Post your code so that we can see what you are doing

Comment: Probably related: [How to copy java.util.list Collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457087/how-to-copy-java-util-list-collection)

Comment: I have just edited my question and added a piece of code.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You may create a new list with an input of a previous list like so:

```
List one = new ArrayList()
//... add data, sort, etc
List two = new ArrayList(one);
```

This will allow you to modify the order or what elemtents are contained independent of the first list.

Keep in mind that the two lists will contain the same objects though, so if you modify an object in List two, the same object will be modified in list one.

example:

```
MyObject value1 = one.get(0);
MyObject value2 = two.get(0);
value1 == value2 //true
value1.setName("hello");
value2.getName(); //returns "hello"
```

**Edit**

To avoid this you need a deep copy of each element in the list like so:

```
List<Torero> one = new ArrayList<Torero>();
//add elements

List<Torero> two = new Arraylist<Torero>();
for(Torero t : one){
    Torero copy = deepCopy(t);
    two.add(copy);
}
```

with copy like the following:

```
public Torero deepCopy(Torero input){
    Torero copy = new Torero();
    copy.setValue(input.getValue());//.. copy primitives, deep copy objects again

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: But this is what I want to avoid, for example, if I change value2 on List two, I don't want to propagate this change on List one.

Comment: Ah, that changes things, do you have a method or constructor to copy one Torero to another?

Comment: No, I don't have any, could you give me any clue?

Comment: It's works, but I was avoiding to set manually every element of the object. I understand there is any alternative...

Thanks.

Comment: If you want a libarary to do this work for you, look at Apache Commons BeanUtils.cloneBean().  This uses reflection to copy properties from one object to another.  http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html

Comment: Do note that `new ArrayList<>(x)` will throw an exception if `x` is null!

Answer (score 24):

Use the ArrayList copy constructor, then sort that.

```
List oldList;
List newList = new ArrayList(oldList);
Collections.sort(newList);
```

After making the copy, any changes to newList do not affect oldList.

Note however that only the *references* are copied, so the two lists share the same objects, so changes made to *elements* of one list affect the *elements* of the other.

Comment: Is there any way that changes made to elements of copied list are not being propagated?

Comment: It is technically not propagation as you have multiple references to the very same object. You either have to make copies (which lowers both time and space effectivity) or use immutable objects (or immutable wrappers around mutable objects).