# Unintended modification in Java

Tags: java

I have the following Java code:

```java
List<List<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(rankings);
for (int i = k + 1; i < rankings.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rankings.get(0).size(); j++) {
        int index = rankings.get(i).indexOf(j);
        list1.get(i).set(index, map.get(j));
    }
}
// ...
int newrank = sort(list1.get(i), 0, list1.get(i).size() - 1); // sorts list1
```

`list1` came out sorted, but `rankings` came out sorted as well. How can I prevent this?

All I wanted to do is to create a duplicate of `rankings` so that the original copy won't be affected while I sort the temporary, copied array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to make a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457087/how-to-copy-java-util-list-collection) of `rankings`.

Comment: That `sort()` call will sort each sub-list (assuming it's inside an `i` loop that isn't shown in the code), but will not sort `list1` itself. What you're claiming is wrong!

Comment: What is `map`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new ArrayList<>(list)` copies the reference here, not cloning the objects,  every amends made in one element will affect both lists.

You can add the elements manually to clone it:

```
    for (List<Integer> intList: rankings) {
        List<Integer> someIntCopy = new ArrayList<>();
        someIntCopy.addAll(intList);
        list1.add(someIntCopy);
    }
```